# How does one discern between atomic, relational, and intentional adjectives?

Tags: reference-request, adjectives

Some adjectives are atomic. They're just there and they presuppose nothing. Jolly is an example of this. "Bobby is a jolly boy" tells you everything you need to know about Bobby.

Other adjectives are relational. Ignorant is one such example. "Bobby is ignorant". Ignorant... of what? The Gospel? His true father?

And other adjectives are intentional, because they have an "aboutness" to them. Vigilant is an example of this. "Bobby is vigilant". Vigilant... about what? About his health?

How does one sort an adjective as atomic, relational, or intentional? Have some scholars made a database of English adjectives where they attached this feature as a meta tag? Are there linguistic tests, something like a flowchart, one can perform to sort them?

Comment: I don't see what is distinctive about your "intentional" category. Isn't *vigilant* also just a relational adjective?

Comment: @curiousdannii intentional adjectives take "about" as a preposition while relational adjectives take "of" as a preposition. It isn't good English to say *"he is vigilant of his health"

Comment: Relations in linguistics aren't limited to one type of preposition. That seems to be an arbitrary restriction. If you want to divide adjectives according to the prepositions they license, well that's fine, but you'll have to make that database yourself :)